# chrome extensions - can't get non secure cookies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension which fetches cookies of a different domain.

I'm using chrome.cookies API, i.e.

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({},function(cookies){console.log(cookies.length)})
```

however, it seems that I can get only cookies marked as secure.
using {secure: false} as filter object I get no results.

Also, the cookies marked as secure are actually only one, so I can't be 100% sure that chrome is actually filtering on secure cookies.

The manifest should be set up correctly (with "cookies" as permission and the correct domain)
Is there something I am missing?

Comment: doesnt {secure: false} get all the non-secure cookies, and not the secure ones?  Also secure works only on https domains.

Comment: Are you sure there are actually non-secure cookies?

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but still unanswered and coming up in searches.
If your manifest.json specifically requests access to `https://foo.bar`, you won't have access to unsecure cookies.

=> Change it to `*://foo.bar`